# How to sum some of the values for dicts in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

Im having a protocol in Yatzee, containing of e dict object for every player in a list, called protocol.

I´m looking for a way to sum some of the values in the dict?
Every dict is having these moments:

```
Ettor
Tvåor
Treor
Fyror
Femmor
Sexor
Summa
Bonus
Par
Tvåpar
Triss
Fyrtal
Stege(liten)
Stege(stor)
Kåk
Chans
Yatzy
Summa
```

connected to a value. I would like to sum the first 6 and later sum all except the last one(which is supposed to be the sum).

Thanks for helping

Comment: why do you want to make the sum of the score outside the player class?

Comment: Why don't you use english for your variables and functions?

Comment: I´m not sure, all my other functions like def GivePoints and def PrintProtocol is outside the class. Would it be better to have it inside and in that case, how?

Comment: added the implementation to the answer below. I also suggest that you comment your code more and change the parameters to English ones like septi suggested. This makes reuse of your code more easy.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. Spend some time thinking before you code; which operations make sense on which objects? If you're having trouble, perhaps `OrderedDict` isn't the best data structure? If you're going to keep asking questions here, it would probably be wise to code in English (as the style guide recommends, *"unless you are 120% sure that the code will never be read by people who don't speak your language"*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary does not remember the order for elements. I think for this case using orderDict would be a bit overkill. Try to keep your types as simple as possible (unless you need the order for your print statement).

I personally think that the best approach is to have two dictionaries for a player. One for the first 6 types of rolls (if I remember playing yahtzee correctly) and one for the special rolls and bonusses.

Secondly, because the names of the rolls are independent of the players I would add them as static parameters to the class. This way you don't have to pass them as arguments of the constructor. It makes it cleaner to make a new player (and also more logical). I suggest you read into object oriented programming (OOP). This would improve your coding a lot.

It would also be logical to add the sum function of the score to the player class. Each player has a score that updates through the game (or is calculated at the end of the game). The class will look like this:

```
Class Player(Object):
    #static variables valid for all players:
    momentList1=() #add the names of the first 6 moments here
    momentList2=() #add the names of the other moments here

    def __init__(self, namn):
        self.namn = namn
        self.moment1 = {}
        self.moment2 = {}
        for ett_moment in Player.momentlist1:
            self.moment1[ett_moment]= 0
        for moment in Player.momentList2:
            self.moment2[moment]=0

    def gepoang(self, v_moment, v_poang):
       self.moment[v_moment]= v_poang

    def __str__(self):
       return self.namn + str(self.moment)

    def sumScore(self):
        # reset sum to 0, this allows multiple calls of sumScore without introducing errors
        sum1=0 
        sum2=0
        # loop over the first dict containing the rolls 1 -> 6
        for key in self.moment1: sum1+=self.moment1[key]
        # add the sum of the first 6 rolls to the second dict
        self.moment2[summa]=sum1
        # add the bonus to the second dict
        if (self.moment2[summa]>63): self.moment2[bonus]=50  
        for key in self.moment2: sum2+=self.moment2[key]
        return sum2
```

If you only want to use one dictionary (and not change your object) to hold all items you can iterate a list with the elements to sum first:

```
def sumFirstSix(self):
    """
    sums the first six moments and returns the sum of the values
    """
    l=('Ettor','Tvåor','Treor','Fyror','Femmor','Sexor')
    sum=0
    for item in l:
        sum+=self.moment[item]
    return sum
```

Comment: please also up-vote the answer to distinguish between the proposed answers.

Answer (score 0):

So first we have to mention, that `moment` is an `OrderedDict`. Because without ordering the term *first six* makes no sense normal dict.

With this, you could simply iterate over the key value pairs `kv` in the `OrderedDict`, and sum the values. So if you want to sum the values of the first six items of `moment` it would look like

```
sum([kv[1] for i, kv in enumerate(moment.iteritems()) if i < 6])
```

Does this help?

Comment: I got this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mans/Desktop/P-Uppgift/Yatzy_huvudprogram2.py", line 211, in <module>
    meny()
  File "/Users/Mans/Desktop/P-Uppgift/Yatzy_huvudprogram2.py", line 203, in meny
    summering(protokoll)
  File "/Users/Mans/Desktop/P-Uppgift/Yatzy_huvudprogram2.py", line 29, in summering
    oversumma = sum([kv[1] for i, kv in enumerate(moment.iteritems()) if i < 6])
NameError: name 'moment' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Of course you have to adapt the code a little bit. So for example, if you paste it in your method `summering`, you have to write `self.moment`